# Why am I getting a "Possible Null Reference" Warning on an Enum->String conversion?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a private field of type `ArmorType`. It's an `enum`. I then make a public property that returns that `enum` value as a `string`. But then Visual Studio 2022 tells me that there is a `Possible Null Reference Return` and I am completely confused as to how that could ever be possible, given that an enum value cannot be null so the returned string could also never be null.

[image]

Any explanation as to why? Is Visual Studio just being dumb? Am I missing something fundamental about how C# functions?

Comment: "Returns: A string containing the name of the enumerated constant in enumType whose value is value; or null if no such constant is found." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=net-8.0

Comment: Ah, so in the event you pass a mismatched object to the `value` part of the `Enum.GetName()` call, you might get a null value. Is that correct?

Comment: Because `Enum.GetName<T>((T)-1);`. FYI just `armorType.ToString();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value, the GetName method guarantees that it will return the name of one of those enumeration members. However, it does not guarantee that it will always return the name of the same enumeration member. As a result, when multiple enumeration members have the same value, your application code should never depend on the method returning a particular member's name.

```
private ArmorType armorType;
public string ArmorType => Enum.GetName(typeof(ArmorType), armorType)!;
```

in net core 8.

Answer (score 0):

You're using project setting "enable nullable reference types". you have declared a not-nullable property `ArmorType`, (`string` vs `string?`).

Now, you're trying to use `Enum.GetName()` declared as

```
public static string? GetName (Type enumType, object value);
```

As you see, it returns nullable `string`. And you're trying to return it via non-nullable property `string`. Hence, you get this compiler error.

You can declare your property as nullable string or if you guaranteed correct value in `this.armorType` you can use null-forgiving operator `!` as in `this.armorType!`